# Can you *really* change the author in Git

Tags: git, github

Sounds like a standard "can I change the author of a Git commit" question but it's not really...

...my question is given you have changed an author via `git commit --amend --author="Dr Evil <dr.evil@worlddomination.org>"` is it *really* lost? Can it be recovered if the `reflog` for example?

What about other scenarios? I know a author can naturally change after a squash/rebase type activity, but I assume in those cases, you still have the history in the tree somewhere? How can it be retrieved?

Any kind of summary about recovering this kind of thing or even pulling it out in a report would be very helpful. I'm concerned with auditing and showing the author can't be nefariously faked. I appreciate the signature can help here but vaguely remember that if an author changes, the new author would themselves sign the commit - so it doesn't ensure anything other than the (potentially up to no good new) author is who she says she is.

Comment: A revision object can't be modified once it's created (if something as the author changes, you will get a different revision with a different ID). If you _rewrite history_, you are creating new revision objects and then you could set up new authors (for those new revision objects). And sure, reflog points to other revision objects. As long as those revisions exist, you can always check their author... but what matters is what comprises the history of a branch... well, under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

The author on an existing commit can be changed (or "faked" if you will). But technically that is only because it is being replaced by a new commit, that is identical to the old one, except that the author is different and consequently the hash of the commit is different.

The commit with the original author (and original hash) is still in the reflog.  By default the reflog only retains commits for 2 weeks.

The most straightforward way to prevent wanton rewriting of history is to prevent ordinary users from using `push -f`.  This is done via a pre-commit hook.  Once a particular history has been pushed, there is no way to "rewrite" it except with a `push -f`.

Comment: The default reflog expiry for unreachable commits (including most amended commits) is 30 days, not 2 weeks, but otherwise, quite right. (The default expiry for *reachable* commits is 90 days. Both defaults can be changed, of course.)

Comment: @torek, thanks for pointing that out.  I think I'm remembering a former default

Comment: You can also require developers to sign commits. I don't think that can be faked.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon, sure but it's just not as easy to set up as a pre-commit hook

Comment: Is there a standard approach to either limiting to reporting on change of authorship? Assuming that's important to you (I'm not sure why I should care)

Comment: @JoelFan I use gitea for code review and you can set protected branches that require signed commits. No hook needed. I assume github/gitlab have similar features.

Comment: @toby, as for "limiting", I mentioned the pre-commit hook in my answer.  "Reporting" seems to me like it would be difficult, without analyzing the reflog.  Easier to just prevent it.